# caffe how to set a filter using matlab?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

I want to update a convolutional filter using matlab in Caffe.
How can I do it?
so far my code is:

```
caffe.reset_all(); % reset caffe
caffe.set_mode_gpu();
gpu_id = 0;  % we will use the first gpu in this demo
caffe.set_device(gpu_id);

net_model = [model_dir, 'train_images.prototxt'];
net = caffe.Net(net_model, 'train');

net.blobs('conv1').set_data([1,1,0]);
```

Comment: and what is wrong with your code?

Comment: you'll have to post the prototxt of at least the `conv1` layer

Comment: you should have posted the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36551284/1714410) here.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine.

```
caffe.reset_all(); % reset caffe
caffe.set_mode_gpu();  
gpu_id = 0;  % we will use the first gpu in this demo    
caffe.set_device(gpu_id);
net_model = ['net_images.prototxt'];
net = caffe.Net(net_model, 'train')
a = zeros(1,1,3,2);
a(1,1,:,:) = [[1,0,0];[0,1,0]]'; % caffe uses BGR color channel order
         net.layers('select_B_G').params(1).set_data(a);
solver = caffe.Solver(solverFN);
solver.solve();
net.save(fullfile(model_dir, 'my_net.caffemodel'));
```